# Flume setup in local

Tags: flume, morphline

Can I do setup of flume on my local machine?

I can only see setup guides for flume on a cluster environment.

I have to setup flume and have to integrate it with morphline.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Installing Flume in local is straightforward. Just download the flume distribution from CDH repo and set all the environment variables like HADOOP_HOME,JAVA_HOME etc and configure the flume configuration file.